# Swift thinks my protocol has associated type requirements, but they're explicitly defined

Tags: swift

I have the following protocol:

```
protocol Device: AnyObject, Identifiable where ID == String {
    var id: String { get }
    var name: String { get }
    var isConnected: Bool { get }
    func connect()
    func disconnect()
}
```

When I use it like this:

```
class ConnectionManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published private (set) var devices = [Device]()
}
```

I get this error:

```
Protocol 'Device' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

Removing the `Identifiable` definition gets rid of this warning, but I need that definition to satisfy usage in SwiftUI.

Aren't the associated type requirements already satisfied by explicitly defining `ID` as `String`?

I'm using Xcode 13.1 / Swift 5.5.

Comment: "Aren't the associated type requirements already satisfied by explicitly defining ID as String" You have resolved the generic but it is still a generic protocol, and therefore Device is a generic protocol, and therefore it cannot be the type of an element of an array. In any case your code is a Bad Smell; any time you think of making an array of some protocol, you need to think again.

Comment: I guess. I'm moving towards a type erasure solution where I define an `AnyDevice` alongside a `Device` protocol so I can have a common interface and can hold references. Type erasure seems more like a workaround of Swift limitations rather than a superior pattern, though.

Comment: Maybe. I still don't see the point of the protocol so it's hard to suggest an alternative.

Comment: I have several types of devices each with a separate implementation (e.g. USB, WebSocket, Bluetooth, etc.). I want to join them together in a single set and operate on the elements of that set with a common interface.

Comment: And this can't be a class and its subclasses? Or a struct injected as a dependency? Keep in mind, a protocol is not a real type. An array of protocols is contraindicated. Think of another architecture.

Comment: My first thought was subclassing an abstract class, actually. That is kind of hacky in Swift though so I abandoned the approach, but maybe I should revisit. Isn't dependency injection basically the way the type erasure pattern would work? I'd be injecting a struct (or a class) conforming to the "Device" protocol into an "AnyDevice" to act as the real type.

Comment: @matt I went with subclassing, which gave me a very natural pattern to work with. Works very similar to a UIViewController pattern now. Was even able to drop Combine entirely in favor of some tried-and-true delegate patterns. Much more straight-forward. I do wish Swift had first-class support for abstract classes, though! Anyway, thank you for the challenge to rethink my approach.

Comment: If the problem is solved, please either answer your own question (totally legal) or delete it. Thanks!